# Simple Data Flow not extracting all records in table

Tags: ssis, dataflowtask

I am working in Visual Studio 2010 on SQL 2012. (We are in the process of moving to 2019 but it is not live yet.)  A couple of weeks ago I built a simple package that uses a data flow to extract rows from a table to a flat file.  Nothing special about it, straight mapping, all columns.   I ran it yesterday and it produced a file with only 3/4 of the rows.

I ran the deployed version, the development package and the task itself.  All producing a file with only 3/4 of the rows.  I also tried a new flat file, got the same result.

Sorry, I meant to add that I rebuilt the data flow task and flat file and it is working fine now.

Curious if anyone else has seen this issue?

Thanks

Maggie

Comment: There could be a lot of issues.  Are you sure your connected to the right server with all the records?  Is there bad data causing some rows to fail/not get exported?  Or malformed data causing some lines to merge.  Could be tons of issues, post more of your code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to add that I rebuilt the data flow task and flat file and it is working fine now.